# R 'effects' plot - dichotomizing variable with 'xlevels' with cut-off-values

Tags: r, data-visualization, effects

lets say I want to dichotomize a previously continuous variable (e.g. Age) of a mixed-effect model (lme4) into two levels directly in the `effects` function in R (Age 8-12 and Age 13-16).

I know with `xlevels=list(Age=2)` I could get my 2 levels right away, but I do not find any information on which rule this classification is based.

Here there is my command:

```
effect("Age",model,xlevels=list(Age=c(12))
```

Let's say I set 12 to a cutoff (12 still belonging to the lower level), this doesn't work, because two input values are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't dichotomoize directly in the `effects` function, because the `xlevels`-argument considers input of length one as amount of equally spaced levels, see `?effect`:

> If xlevels=n is an integer, then each numeric predictor is represented by n equally spaced levels

Thus, `xlevels=list(Age=2)` will simply try to find two values of your Age-variable that are "equally spaced" (which most likely will be the minimum and maximum value of Age).

If you specify more than one value, e.g. `xlevels=list(Age=c(2, 4, 6, 8)`, then the `effect`-function will return the predicted values for Age = 2, Age = 4, Age = 6 and Age = 8.

Maybe you could get the mean from your two ranges, 8-12 = 10 and 13-16 = 14.5, and use these values for the `xlevels`-argument (`xlevels=list(Age=c(10, 14.5)`). I don't know if this comes close to dichotomizing...